# Sorting list of string

Tags: c#, sorting

Let me re ask this question

Say I have two tables in a database one being tasks and the other being Dependencies

The task table has one column (taskName) with all the tasks that needs to be run

The taskDependency table has 2 columns one being tasks (taskNames) and the other dependencies (taskDependsOn)

Now say I select the tasks from the task table into a list and the dependencies for the dependencies table into a List.(Dictionary wont work as some tasks has multiple dependencies)

How would I get the tasks into the right order?

Edit

I got the answer on another forum and thought ill share it here.

You can use a Dictionary, you just have to use it wisely!

Try a Dictionary> where the key is a task name and the value is the set of task names of those tasks upon which the key depends.

Preload the Dictionary with an empty HashSet for every possible task (table 1).
Update it from the DB (table 2)
Create the empty output List
Then the order is:
1. find the keys with empty dependency sets, there is no order in this group, append these to the output list (and remove them from the Dictionary).
keep a separate list of these.
1a. if the dictionary is empty, you're done.
1b. if no empty dependency sets are found, then you have dependency cycles! FAIL.
2. for all of the remaining sets in the Dictionary (i.e., the dictionary.Values)
3. remove from the set all of the tasks found in step 1.
4. back to step 1.

Thanx Mat from CodeProject

Comment: In what language? Sort according to List 2?

Comment: Not clear what you want. Give an example. What would you expect list 1 to look like after sorting.

Comment: Will you have fixed amount of elements in both containers?

Comment: what is the type of `List2` ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what your data structures are (list or arrays) but if `list1` is a `list<string>` or `string[]` and `list2` is a `List<List<string>>` or `List<string[]>` or `string[][]` then the query would be:

```
from str in list1
join pair in list2 on str = pair[0]
order by pair[1]
select str
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> ordering = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
               { "g", "d" }, { "s", "e" }, { "e", "g" }
            };
        List<string> source = new List<string>() { "e", "s", "g" };

        List<string> result = source.OrderBy(key => ordering[key]).ToList();

        foreach (string s in result) { Console.Write(s + " "); }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

the result is `g s e`.

Comment: What if one item depends om more than one value/

Comment: Then change the value for OrderBy!

Comment: But a Dictionary cnt have 2 of the same keys

Comment: The dictionary is immaterial. What's important is that you are sorting a list of string by using another string and that string is coming from some other place (in this case a dictionary), which is more or less what you asked for, right?

Comment: That is correct, have been trying to take that logic and applying it to my senario to no avail

Answer (score 0):

A vector sort, where we're ordering one vector in terms of another? Something like this?

```
// first, our base data
Tuple<char,char>[] data = { new Tuple<char,char>('g','d') ,
                            new Tuple<char,char>('s','e') , 
                            new Tuple<char,char>('d','s') , 
                            new Tuple<char,char>('e','g') , 
                          } ;

// initialize the two vectors
List<char>             keys   = new List<char>( data.Select(x => x.Item1 ) ) ; // {g,d,s,e}
List<Tuple<char,char>> values = new List<Tuple<char, char>>( data ) ;

// An in-place sort of the "keys" vector in terms of the payload of the "values" vector
keys.Sort( (x,y) => {

  // first, find the associated value for each key (if such exists)
  char? xValue = null ;
  char? yValue = null ;
  foreach (Tuple<char, char> t in values)
  {
    if ( t.Item1 == x && !xValue.HasValue ) xValue = t.Item2 ;
    if ( t.Item1 == y && !yValue.HasValue ) yValue = t.Item2 ;
    // if we found both values, we can quit                 
    if ( xValue.HasValue && yValue.HasValue  ) break ;
  }

  // set the condition (comparison code)
  int cc ;
  if      ( xValue.HasValue && yValue.HasValue ) cc =  xValue.Value.CompareTo( yValue.Value) ;
  else if ( xValue.HasValue                    ) cc = +1 ; // treat NULL as collating lower than non-null
  else if (                    yValue.HasValue ) cc = -1 ; // treat NULL as collating lower than non-null
  else                                           cc =  0 ; // equal if both are NULL

  // return it
  return cc ;
});
```